# Dynamically calling variables in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have the following variable file

```
$ cat variables.yaml
cluster1:
   - name: k8sb1
     project: foo
     id: 46
cluster2:
   - name: k8sc1
     project: bar
     id: 89
```

The variables under `cluster1` and `cluster2` may grow dynamically, e.g.

```
cluster1:
   - name: k8sb1
     project: foo
     id: 67
   - name: k8sb2
     project: foo2
     id: 69
```

I have following task file

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Create project for {{ cluster }}
    command: kubectl create ns {{ cluster.project }}
```

My ansible command is

```
ansible-playbook -e @variables.yaml -e cluster=cluster1
```

I thought this would fetches all the names under `cluster1` (E.g. foo, foo1, foo2 etc, the one under `porject` field in variable).
and this would expand in creating a loop of the following command on the target machine.

```
kubectl create ns foo
kubectl create ns foo2
```

However, it is failing with the undefined variable `project`, but in fact, it is defined in the variable file.

```
$ ansible-playbook -e cluster=cluster1 -e @variables.yaml playbook.yaml 
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Create project for cluster1] *******************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'project'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/ansible/playbook.yaml': line 3, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n  - name: Create project for {{ cluster }}\n    ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/root/ansible/playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

May I know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible is not capable of indirect addressing. You need *lookup* *vars* plugin if you want to fetch a value of a variable name of which is stored in another variable, e.g. given the file

```yaml
shell> cat variables.yaml 
cluster1:
   - name: k8sb1
     project: foo
     id: 67
   - name: k8sb2
     project: foo2
     id: 69
```

the play

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ lookup('vars', cluster) }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e @variables.yaml -e cluster=cluster1

ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'k8sb1', 'project': 'foo', 'id': 67}) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item:
    id: 67
    name: k8sb1
    project: foo

ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'k8sb2', 'project': 'foo2', 'id': 69}) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item:
    id: 69
    name: k8sb2
    project: foo2
```